# Keep Top 1000 rows from table by dropping and inserting new table?

Tags: sql, ssms

I am paring down a database for a small project. I heard the most efficient way to get a table down to just 1000 rows was to copy those 1000 rows to a new table drop the old and rename the new.

Could someone let me know if this is right and roughly how to do it?

I know how to select top 1000 but not how to drop and create a table by using a temp table or the like.

Comment: So... I'm assuming that you want to keep the same constraints, keys, indexes, triggers as the original table, correct?

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE
SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM OLD_TABLE

DROP TABLE OLD_TABLE
```

Comment: Works for the **data** - but all constraints, indexes etc. from the `OLD_TABLE` are **gone** in `NEW_TABLE` ....

Answer (score 0):

You can run this to create your new table:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 * INTO NewTable FROM OldTable
```

USING SELECT INTO will create a new table.  Drawbacks of this method are you lose your keys on your table.

Alternatively, if the table exists, use

```
INSERT INTO NewTable SELECT * FROM OldTable
```

However, if you have an Identity field, this won't work -- you'll need to specify the column names

```
INSERT INTO NewTable (Field1, Field2,...) SELECT Field1, Field2...
```

As you can see, it really depends on your situation.

To drop a table, it's pretty easy:

```
DROP TABLE OldTable
```

Good luck.